# Translog durability (Elasticsearch)

Tags: elasticsearch

I have read about translog from [ElasticSearch official doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-translog.html) but I didn't get answer to below question. I tried to find-out at other places but not able to find the answer.
In doc it is mentioned for index.translog.durability=request means

```
(default) fsync and commit after every request. In the event of hardware failure, all acknowledged writes will already have been committed to disk.
```

here mentioned commit is Lucene commit? Lucene commit is expensive & due to this only translog is introduced. then why default value of this property is request. It should be async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translog commit is a disk commit(append some log to a file), not a Lucene commit.

Translog is a common way to ensure durability in many databases, like mysql, elasticsearch, redis.

Before a request is written to a lucene index, it will be written into translog. If the former failed (for example, elasticsearch server is down),
when you restart elasticsearch server, it will replay the translog.

1. The default value of this property is request, which means translog is committed to disk by request. It ensures highest durablity.
2. One the other hand, async means after some period (index.translog.sync_interval), translog will commit to disk. It imporves performance, with lower durablity.